# Compare two json files and add number to object if object with same value is still there

Tags: javascript, node.js

Lets say i have 2 Json responses from a server, one of which is 30 seconds older that the new one. How would i be able to check if an object is still inside the response and after testing if it is still there update an object in another json file to add +1 to the number of that object.

(an example because i can´t explain)

**JSON coming in** 
"names and id´s in json changed"

```
{
    "description": "Insert description here;", 
    "favicon": null, 
    "latency": 78.085, 
    "players": {
      "max": 20, 
      "online": 3, 
      "sample": [
        {
          "id": "07bda75d-d8d2-4108-94a7-ba2c09127nsj", 
          "name": "oajhebskaa"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "8d8aac43-112b-402b-8771-67b49183lazf", 
          "name": "jahebianl"
        }, 
        {
          "id": "67d8a66b-ce37-439f-9020-e6de827dn2o9", 
          "name": "ffwqehas"
        }
      ]
    }, 
    "version": {
      "name": "Paper 1.16.4", 
      "protocol": 754
    }
  }
```

**After cutting out wanted values it looks like this :**

```
[
  '07bda75d-d8d2-4108-94a7-ba2c09127nsj',
  '8d8aac43-112b-402b-8771-67b49183lazf',
  '67d8a66b-ce37-439f-9020-e6de827dn2o9'
]
```

**What i want to do**

Now upon a new response coming in i want to update another json file which should idealy look something like this...

```
{
   "players" : [
      { "07bda75d-d8d2-4108-94a7-ba2c09127nsj": "0" },
      { "8d8aac43-112b-402b-8771-67b49183lazf": "0" },
      { "67d8a66b-ce37-439f-9020-e6de827dn2o9": "0" }
   ]
}
```

...and add 1 to the number behind a the certain playerid.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with

```
{
   "players" : [
      { "07bda75d-d8d2-4108-94a7-ba2c09127nsj": "0" },
      { "8d8aac43-112b-402b-8771-67b49183lazf": "0" },
      { "67d8a66b-ce37-439f-9020-e6de827dn2o9": "0" }
   ]
}

let mainObj = JSON.parse(response1);
let players = JSON.parse(response2);

for (let entry of mainObj.players.sample) {
   if (players.players.indexOf(entry.id) > -1) {
     players.players[entry.id]++;
    }
}
```

I don't have a chance to test it right this moment, give it a shot, and it should put you on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work.

```js
let samplePayload = {
  "description": "Insert description here;",
  "favicon": null,
  "latency": 78.085,
  "players": {
    "max": 20,
    "online": 3,
    "sample": [{
        "id": "07bda75d-d8d2-4108-94a7-ba2c09127nsj",
        "name": "oajhebskaa"
      },
      {
        "id": "8d8aac43-112b-402b-8771-67b49183lazf",
        "name": "jahebianl"
      },
      {
        "id": "67d8a66b-ce37-439f-9020-e6de827dn2o9",
        "name": "ffwqehas"
      }
    ]
  },
  "version": {
    "name": "Paper 1.16.4",
    "protocol": 754
  }
};

let previousResponseIds = [];
let trackingObj = {};

function responseMiddleware(payload) {
  let responseIds = payload.players.sample.map(v => v.id);
  let matches = previousResponseIds.filter(v => responseIds.find(x => x === v));
  for (let i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
    if (trackingObj.hasOwnProperty(matches[i])) trackingObj[matches[i]] += 1;
    else trackingObj[matches[i]] = 0;
  }
  previousResponseIds = responseIds;
}

/*UI below*/
let pre = document.getElementsByTagName('pre')[0];
(function updateUI() {
  pre.innerText = JSON.stringify(trackingObj, null, 1);
  setTimeout(updateUI, 200);
})();
document.getElementById("AddResponse").addEventListener("click", function() {
  responseMiddleware(samplePayload);
});
```

```html
<strong>trackingObj:</strong>
<pre></pre>
<button id="AddResponse">Simulate Response</button>
```